# How to download a file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, download

Hi is there any chance to download a file into local system without displaying downloading process at the front end ?

I am trying as below

```
   var f = document.createElement("iframe");
   f.setAttribute("id", "theFrame");
   document.body.appendChild(f);
   document.getElementById("theFrame").location = 'http://www.example.com/yourfile.doc';
```

I am able to download the file but it was displaying in the front end of the browser as the file is getting download.

Comment: A simple google search will tell you this is a security risk and impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is not possible.

A web site is by definition untrusted. And you don't want to let untrusted web sites make changes to your system, even if it is 'just' a file download (which could be potentially dangerous since it can contain a virus for example).

Therefore a browser will show the download to the user as it thinks it is appropriate. Nothing you can do about that.

(As you have built already, you *can* download it without permission, you just can't *hide* the download)

Comment: Yup -- with the "not possible" part being the "without displaying downloading process at the front end." It's entirely possible for a web page to initiate a download when loaded (not just assets).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed. This is considered a feature by most browser builders. Not so happy with it either. That's what I meant with 'the browser thinks is appropriate', it doesn't have to be our opinion about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. When the browser detects a file download it will show up in the download bar and you can't (at least you shouldn't be able to) stop this - it's the way the browser works and has nothing to do with javascript/php code.

I also can't think of any use case where you would want to hide this from your user, except for malicious intent (like a virus).